# Converting a n-element Vector{Vector{Int64}} to a Vector{Int64}

Tags: julia

I have a list of vectors (vector of vectors) like the following:

`A 2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}: A= [347229118, 1954075737, 6542148346,347229123, 1954075753, 6542148341] [247492691, 247490813, -2796091443606465490, 247491615, 247492910, 247491620, -4267071114472318843, 747753505]`

the goal is to have them all in just one vector. I did try `collect`, `A[:]`, `vec(A)`, `flatten(A)` but it still returns `2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}`
I don't know what command I should use. Is there anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your input data is:

```
julia> x = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
3-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2]
 [3, 4]
 [5, 6]
```

here are some natural options you have.

Option 1: use `Iterators.flatten`:

```
julia> collect(Iterators.flatten(x))
6-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```

You can omit `collect` in which case you get a lazy iterator over the source data which is more memory efficient.

Option 2: use `vcat`:

```
julia> reduce(vcat, x)
6-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```

You could also write:

```
julia> vcat(x...)
6-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```

but splatting might get problematic if your `x` vector is very long. In which case I recommend you to use the `reduce` function as shown above.

Comment: Very useful! Super thanks!